# How to make yt-dlp JSON data not return null when a YouTube video is in "upcoming" mode?

Tags: windows, windows-10, youtube, debug, yt-dlp

The following command works for me (meaning it returns JSON data for the video):

```
yt-dlp.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1C0ZtmBlL-s --skip-download --dump-single-json --no-check-certificate --restrict-filenames
```

However, the same command but for a video which has yet to "premiere" (it's in "upcoming" mode) does not return any JSON data! It outputs null and error-logs an English text saying: "Premieres in 3 hours", which is useless to me:

```
yt-dlp.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNWB7wu9hjE --skip-download --dump-single-json --no-check-certificate --restrict-filenames
```

I need to be able to see the timestamp when it premieres, before it premieres, in order to automatically insert a reminder for myself. This information **is** available on the YouTube webpage, so the information *does* exist: `"isUpcoming":true` and `"scheduledStartTime"`

Furthermore, yt-dlp literally has a `live_status` property in the JSON output, which can be `is_upcoming`, according to its manual, so it makes *no sense* that my command doesn't return anything when the video is "upcoming". The data is available, and yt-dlp seemingly supports it. So why is the output null when the video is in "upcoming" state?

PS: Depending on when you read this, the video in the second link may no longer be "upcoming". It's upcoming for 32 minutes more at the time of publishing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `--ignore-no-formats-error` to the command as that's the error that's thrown if no video format can be downloaded.

For example:

```
yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rG0m71ilPuY --skip-download --dump-single-json --no-check-certificate --restrict-filenames --ignore-no-formats-error
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#verbosity-and-simulation-options)

Comment: Thank you. I assume that this works, but I cannot test it. I have been searching and searching for a video that is premiering in order to test it, but cannot find anything when I need it...

Comment: There's one in the example currently for over an hour.

Comment: D'oh! Of course! Thanks! Yes! It works! I would've also upvoted if the site'd let me.